# Bank statement for a UK visa

Tags: visa-refusals

If I submitted a bank statement for a standard visitor visa and my visa was rejected due to not knowing the origin of the funds, what will happen if I submit another statement but not for a year, it will be only six months and the money in it is my inheritance. I have the legacy notification statement to prove it. Will that be enough?
They told me that the money in my account remains unaccounted for.[image]

Comment: Can you post a picture of the refusal letter with your personal information blanked out? Being able to prove the origin of the funds is a much better plan than trying to optimise your bank statements submission.

Comment: actually they are really my inheritence but my cover letter wasn't so clear

Comment: it was mixed with another account but i didn't write every account number and what it was used for so everything got mixed up

Comment: The person reviewing your new application is not an idiot and will see the reason your previous application(s) was(were) refused. You can't just leave inconvenient details out of a new application when your history is right in front of them. Your only way forward is to do what they've asked and explain what they're looking for.

Comment: .. and how is this new question any different from the one you asked yetserday? https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/109958/uk-standard-visitor-visa-rejection

Comment: I didn't say i will not reply to the previous refusal ... I just said that he linked the wrong account with the company so how do you suggest i explain this situation?

Comment: i never meant to say that my account is related to the company ... i only mentioned the company as a tie but this was the reply in the refusal so how to solve this problem?

Comment: You have two refusals. At this point the best thing to do is get yourself a lawyer with UK immigration expertise. If that is not an option, you can try to make another application yourself. Try to see things from the officer's perspective: they only have the information you give. You need to clearly explain everything. If you can't explain something as simple as money then you should not be employed doing something as complex as medicine.

Comment: I did not say that the money came from the company in my cover letter. I said it was my inheritence and provided documents to prove this. I don't know why he linked the company to my savings account and i don't know how to reply.

Comment: I only mentioned the company as a tie and a reason to return back after i finish my exam.... Nothing related to it will be used during my trip but this was the refusal

Comment: The money is my inheritence after my father's death

Comment: and lawyers in egypt most of them are just gold diggers ... all they want is money .... guess i have to try again by myself and pray everything goes smooth

Comment: Hire a British lawyer. Not only do they know the system, but they can prevent things like "my cover letter was not so clear", and the other misunderstandings that seem to have arisen with your applications.

Answer (score 7):

**What the officer is looking for is evidence that the money is yours for your personal use.**

When people acquire a company, even by inheritance, their bank balance does not go up. They just become owners of the company. So saying, even with proof, that you inherited a company does not explain why there is a big increase in your bank balance. So you have still not explained where the money came from.

The officer understood you to say that the money came from the company so that you could buy things for the company. If that is why the money was transferred to your personal account, then the money is not for your personal use. You could not use it to buy a trip for yourself to the UK (doing so would be in violation of company rules and probably illegal). So again, if that is the case it does not improve your finances, and it looks to the officer like an attempt to artificially inflate your bank balance (what we call here 'funds parking').

They are also looking for information about the cashflow and profit of your company, in order to see that the amount the company transferred to you was reasonable.

With two refusals you are strongly recommended to employ a UK immigration lawyer for your next application.